# Sending a mail with Sendgrid from a Grails 2.0 application on Heroku

Tags: email, grails, heroku, sendgrid

I'm trying to send emails from my Grails 2.0 app via Sendgrid on Heroku but I can't find the right configuration. I keep getting "Connection refused" exceptions:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:327)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:193)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:180)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:384)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:546)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:495)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:233)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:189)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1359)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:412)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:288)
at grails.plugin.mail.MailMessageBuilder.sendMessage(MailMessageBuilder.groovy:102)
at grails.plugin.mail.MailService.sendMail(MailService.groovy:39)
at MailGrailsPlugin$_configureSendMail_closure6.doCall(MailGrailsPlugin.groovy:149)
```

The latest configuration I tried is the following:

```
grails {
    mail {
        host = "smtp.sendgrid.net"
        port = 587
        username = System.env.SENDGRID_USERNAME
        password = System.env.SENDGRID_PASSWORD
        props = [
                "mail.smtp.protocol":"smtps",
                "mail.smtp.channel":"plain",
                "mail.smtp.auth":"true",
                "mail.debug":"true"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, it seems that it has nothing to do with Heroku or Sendgrid at all. I get the same exception when trying to send emails from localhost via GMail using the very configuration samples in the doc. My best guess is that there is a problem with Grails mail plugin and Grails 2.0

Comment: I think you are right because when I bash into a Heroku dyno "heroku run bash" and then telnet to smtp.sendgrid.net on port 587, it is allowed to connect just fine.

Comment: You could also use the MailGun add-on which has a RESTful API for sending mail.  Here's a Java example: https://github.com/heroku/shareheroku-java/blob/master/app/helpers/EmailHelper.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem came from my Grails configuration. For some reason, my mail config was reset at some point and what I had in Config.groovy was not used. So the app tried to send emails via localhost and that didn't work. I found a workaround to this problem but I don't understand yet why it works.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you might have a firewall or ISP blocking port 587. Try this: http://support.sendgrid.com/entries/131119-help-smtp-port-25-is-being-blocked

Elmer Thomas, Developer Evangelist at SendGrid.com

Comment: As I said, I don't think it has anything to do with SendGrid at the moment, since I don't manage to send messages from my own machine, via SendGrid or GMail for that matter. There seems to be a problem the the Mail plugin in Grails 2.0.